# My site is throwing "connection insecure" in firefox

Tags: firefox, web

I've heard from someone that my site throws "connection is not secure" error in Mozilla Firefox. I checked it at my computer in firefox and it's working fully fine, so is it users problem that this error is thrown or can I do something about it on my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the users firewall, or your website, it could be that the encryption is not strong enough or you can only recieve a valid certificate on your home wifi due to an error in the website, it could also be due to an outdated TLS mechanism.

Comment: If by website on home wifi you mean that this site stands on my wifi it doesn't, I use hosting. Sorry if I sound dumb, I'm just not very skilled in things like that.

Comment: If this answer was helpful can you please mark it as an answer